# Is there a way to have a responsive parallax image always take 100% of the viewpoint?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I've been following this [solution](https://inkplant.com/code/responsive-parallax-images) to add responsiveness to my parallax images in my right grid. The responsiveness is working fine except the image doesn't takes up the WHOLE viewpoint.

I have put a red border around the image to show this: https://jsfiddle.net/65r3bth1/3/

When it becomes responsive, the image doesn't fill up the left side of the viewpoint unless I change the background-size and mess around with my background positioning. Is it possible to ensure my image takes up the whole viewpoint while maintaining its responsiveness?

```
.image-greet {
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/800/800")
    calc(75% + 120px) 50px /120px auto;
    /*calc (middle of right grid + how pushed to the rigth) how far push down from top / zoom*/
    border-top: 20px;
    background-size: 40% auto;
    width: 78%;
    height: 12%;
    margin: 15% auto 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Is it possible to ensure my image takes up the 100% of the viewpoint while maintaining responsiveness in its original background position?

Thank you!

Comment: Not with those margins and paddings and stuff, I assume those actually are there for some content, can it be that there is a container for the background and then an interior container that holds content that has margins etc.?

Comment: @user254694 the reason i have the padding/margins is because the white space gives a picture frame looking through a "window" effect. why would the margins/padding be a problem?

Comment: actually I made a mistake reading the margins, was being bothered by kids at the time, but still I think I must have misunderstood what you want - is it not that you want the background image to be as wide as the viewport - by which I mean it starts at the position 0 left on the page and goes the full viewport width of the page to the right and does not overflow?

Comment: @user254694 yes, if you check the fiddle i don't want the background image to ever  reach the left black grid. I want the responsive image to always fill the red box's viewpoint only

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you are following can be achieved with CSS, without the need for JS, [as you can see in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fgb5p76/5/). Hope this helps!

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.bg {
  background: url('https://loremflickr.com/320/240');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a general good way to make a responsive parallax site but my situation is a little different because i need to calculate the position of my background because it is showing only on the right side of the grid